# How to measure latency and throughput in a Storm topology

Tags: java, performance, clojure, cloud, apache-storm

I'm learning Storm with the example [`ExclamationTopology`](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-starter/blob/master/src/jvm/storm/starter/ExclamationTopology.java). I want measure the latency (the time it takes to add `!!!` to a word) of a bolt and throughput (say, how many words pass through a bolt per second).

From [here](https://www.endgame.com/blog/storm-metrics-how), I can count the number of words and how many times a bolt is executed:

```
_countMetric = new CountMetric();
_wordCountMetric = new MultiCountMetric();


context.registerMetric("execute_count", _countMetric, 5);
context.registerMetric("word_count", _wordCountMetric, 60);
```

I know that the Storm UI gives `Process Latency` and `Execute Latency` and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33558613/storm-huge-discrepancy-between-bolt-latency-and-total-latency) gives a good explanation of what they are.

However, I want to log the latency of every execution of each bolt, and use this information along with the `word_count` to calculate the throughput.

How can I use [Storm Metrics](http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.1/Metrics.html) to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

While your question is straight forward and will be surely for interest for many people, it`s answer is not as trivial as it should be. First of all, we need to clarify, *what exactly we really want to measure*. Throughput and Latency are terms, that can be easily be understood but in things get more complicated in Storms distributed environment.

As depicted in this excellent [blog post](https://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2013/06/21/understanding-storm-internal-message-buffers/), each Storm supervisor has at least 3 **threads** which fulfill different tasks. While the *Worker Receiver Thread* waits for incoming data tuples and aggregates them to a bulk, they are send to the *Worker Executor Thread*. This contains the user logic (in your case the `ExclamationBolt` and a sender that takes care of the outgoing messages. Finally, on every Supervisor Node, there is a **Worker Send Thread** that aggregates messages coming from all executors, aggregates them and send them to the network.

For sure, each of those threads has its own latency and throughput. For the Sender and Receiver Thread, they are largely depending on the buffer sizes, that you can adjust. In your case, you want just to measure latency and throughput of one (execution) bolt - this is possible, but keep in mind that those other threads have their effects on this bolt.

**My approach:**
To obtain latency and throughput, I used the old [Storm Builtin Metrics](http://storm.apache.org/releases/current/Metrics.html). Because I found the documentation not very clear, I o draw a line here: we are **not** using the new [Storm Metric API v2](http://storm.apache.org/releases/2.2.0/metrics_v2.html) and we are **not** using [Cluster Metrics](http://storm.apache.org/releases/current/ClusterMetrics.html).

1. Activate the Storm Logging with placing the following in your `storm.yaml`:

```
topology.metrics.consumer.register:
  - class: "org.apache.storm.metric.LoggingMetricsConsumer"
    parallelism.hint: 1
```

2. You can set the reporting interval with: `topology.builtin.metrics.bucket.size.secs: 10`
3. Run your Query. All metrics are logged every 10 Seconds in a specific metrics-logfile. It is not trivial to find this logfile. Storm creates a `LoggingMetricsConsumer`-Bolt and distributes it among the cluster. On this node, you should find in the Storm logs the corresponding metric file.
4. This metric file contains for each executor the metrics, you are looking for, like: `complete-latency`, `execute-latency` and so on. For throughput, I would use the Queue Metrics that contains e.g.: `arrival_rate_secs` as an estimate of how many tuples are inserted per second. Take care of the multiple threads that are executed on every supervisor.

Good luck!