# Meauring latency of Storm bolts

Tags: apache-storm

I am trying to measure latency of each bolt in a topology. The latency numbers given by Storm is not enough as we want to calculate percentiles. In my current setup, I measure latency of the bolt by measuring time it takes to complete the execute method including call to emit. The assumption with above method is that, the collector's emit will return immediately without calling next bolt instances execute method even if the same executor is shared between current bolt instance and next bolt instance in the topology.

Comment: **See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38838573/how-to-measure-latency-and-throughput-in-a-storm-topology/67901789#67901789)**

Answer (score 0):

By putting the timer at the beginning and end of your execute method (after the emit) you should be fine.

Comment: Does that mean emit method is asynchronous?

Comment: Not necessarily. Emit probably adds the tuple to an internal queue, and the next bolt reads from the queue whenever is ready to process the next tuple. So regardless of what you do on the next bolt, emit always takes the same time and it is very cheap instruction. If you want to measure how long emit takes, just implement one bolt that only emits and measure that. You can then substract this number from the bolt that you are actually measuring.

Comment: 'probably adds the tuple' - Yes, I also assume this is what happens, but just want confirmation.