# Tuples taking more time in reaching from spout to last bolt(aka Complete Latency) is high

Tags: apache-storm

```
Version Info: 
   "org.apache.storm" % "storm-core" % "1.2.1" 
   "org.apache.storm" % "storm-kafka-client" % "1.2.1"
```

I was creating and experimenting with a Storm topology I have created which has 4 bolts and one kafka spout.

I was trying to tune configs like parallelism of these bolts, max-spout-pending, etc to see how much scale I can get out of it. After some configuration config/results looks something like below:

```
max-spout-pending: 1200
Kafka Spout Executors: 10
Num Workers: 10
+----------+-------------+----------+----------------------+
| boltName | Parallelism | Capacity | Execute latency (ms) |
+----------+-------------+----------+----------------------+
| __acker  |          10 | 0.008    | 0.005                |
| bolt1    |          15 | 0.047    | 0.211                |
| bolt2    |         150 | 0.846    | 33.151               |
| bolt3    |        1500 | 0.765    | 289.679              |
| bolt4    |          48 | 0.768    | 10.451               |
+----------+-------------+----------+----------------------+
```

Process latency and Execute latency are almost same. There is an HTTP call involved in bolt 3 which is taking approximately that much time and bolt 2 and bolt 4 are also doing some I/O operation.

While I can see that each bolt can individually process more than 3k, (bolt3: 1500/289.679ms = 5.17k qps, bolt4: 48/10.451ms = 4.59k qps and so on), but overall this topology is processing tuples at only ~3k qps. I am running it on 10 boxes(so one worker per box), having 12 core CPU and 32GB RAM. I have given each worker process -xms 8Gb and -xmx 10Gb, so RAM should also not be constraint. I see GC also happening properly, 4 GC per minute taking around  total time of 350ms in a minute(from flight recording of worker process of 1 minute).

I see `Complete Latency` for each tuple to be around 4 sec, which is something I am not able to understand, as If I compute all time taken by all bolts, it comes around 334 ms, but as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33561598/1610034), tuples can be waiting in buffers, it suggests to increase dop(degree of parallelism), which I have done and reached above state.

I add some more metering and I see tuples are taking on average around 1.3sec to reach from bolt 2 to bolt 3 and 5 sec from bolt 3 to bolt 4. While I understand Storm might be keeping them in it's outbound or inbound buffer, My question is how do I reduce it as these bolts should be able to process more tuples in a second as par my earlier calculation, what is holding them from entering and being processed at faster rate?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue may be due to `ack` tuples, that are used to start and stop the complete latency clock, being stuck waiting at the ackers.

You have a lot of bolts and presumably high throughput which will result in a lot of `ack` messages. Try increasing the number of ackers, using the `topology.acker.executors` config value which will hopefully reduce the queuing delay for the `ack` tuples.

If you are also using a custom metrics consumer you may also want to increase the parallelism of this component too, given the number of bolts you have.

Comment: I had already increased the number of ackers, which were earlier 3, which I increase to 10 and also I don't see Execute Latency of ackers very high, does still your hypothesis holds?

Comment: The execute latency of the Acker on its own will not tell you much, you need to look at the Acker arrival rate as well. The closer the utilisation (arrival rate times the execute latency) is to 1 the longer your ack tuples will wait and the more time will be artificially added to the complete latency value.

Comment: How do I see Acker arrival rate, is it there in some metrics, not able to find in the nimbus UI?

Comment: I also increased ackers to 50 from 10, no affect on performance.